# После создания экземпляра класса Image и присвоения адреса img.src объект приобретает параметры только после повторного вызова события

Tags: javascript, html5

При обработке события onclick первый раз переменные imgWidth & imgHeight не инициализируются размерами изображения и объект myImage без параметров (но в отладчике Chrome - при клике на любой из параметров - параметр обновляется).
При повторном вызове события onclick переменные получают необходимые параметры.
Что можно исправить? Или что создаётся некорректно. Заранее спасибо.

```
<script>
        var myImage = new Image();
        var newWin = null;

        function openWin(e){
            myImage.src = 'gallery/design/p' + e.target.alt + '\.jpg';
            var imgWidth = myImage.width;
            var imgHeight = myImage.height;

            var str = "width=" + myImage.width + ",height=" + myImage.height + ',top=250, left=250';
            newWin = window.open(myImage.src, '', str);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Зачем вы точку экранируете в строке с расширением картинки? Это же не регулярка.

Comment: Это да. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**А - Асинхронность.**

После того, как Вы устанавливаете img.src, картинка начинает сразу грузиться.
И грузится она в общем случае (если ее нет в кеше) - асинхронно. То есть картинка еще не загрузилась, а вы уже пытаетесь прочитать ее свойства, которых еще нету, и в первый раз ничего не получаете.

А когда Вы кликаете второй раз, то картинка грузится уже из кеша, загрузку из кеша если мне не изменяет память, можно считать синхронной.

**Что делать?**
С помощью img.onload обработать данные картинки, когда они уже есть. Если по минимуму менять ваш код, то что-то вроде:

```
function openWin(e){
      myImage.onload = function(){
          var imgWidth = this.width; 
          var imgHeight = this.height;

          var str = "width=" + this.width + ",height=" + this.height + ',top=250, left=250';
          var newWin = window.open(this.src, '', str);
      };

      myImage.src = 'gallery/design/p' + e.target.alt + '\.jpg';
};
```

Обратите внимание, при установке `src` картинка начнет грузиться сразу. Поэтому обработчик `onload` надо устанавливать до установки `src`. Иначе возможна ситуация, когда картинка уже загрузилась (скажем очень быстро из кеша), а обработчик еще не стоит.

Также, если Вы ранее не сталкивались с асинхронностью в js, у вас скорее всего возникнут еще вопросы, потом. В таком случае полезно будет ознакомиться с ответами [к этому вопросу.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ! Действительно асинхронность впереди. Отдельно спасибо за ссылку.